# Prove $(A−C) ∪ (B−C) = (A ∪ B)−C$ using set builder notation and logical equivalences.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove (A−C) ∪ (B−C) = (A ∪ B)−C using set builder notation and logical equivalences. I have an understanding of both separately, but I don't know how to carry out this question using both of them. Help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $A,B,C$ be sets. Then, in set-builder notation, you have
$$
A \cup B = \{x|x \in A \text{ or } x \in B\}.
$$

1. Can you write down the set-builder definitions from LHS and RHS of your problem?
2. Can you use logical equivalence to transform the characteristic of the LHS to the one on the RHS?